# How do I split a string against a character in BASH?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, strings

I would like to be able to split an authorization code by the `-` character so that I can operate on each segment individually. I do not want to use external binaries (`awk`, `grep`) - this is to be as minimalistic as possible. What are some ways I can achieve this?

Here is an example auth code:

`82a8-bd7d-986d-9dc9-41f5-fc02-2c20-3175-097a-c1eb`

Comment: Normally you would use cut.  Why the limitation on external binaries though?

Comment: This is on an embedded Linux device with limited access to them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using the [Internal Field Separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) (`IFS`):

```
AUTH_CODE='82a8-bd7d-986d-9dc9-41f5-fc02-2c20-3175-097a-c1eb'

OIFS=$IFS                   # store old IFS in buffer
IFS='-'                     # set IFS to '-'

for i in ${AUTH_CODE[@]}    # traverse through elements
do
  echo $i
done

IFS=$OIFS                   # reset IFS to default (whitespace)
```

Output:

```
82a8
bd7d
986d
9dc9
41f5
fc02
2c20
3175
097a
c1eb
```

By setting the Internal Field Separator, you split `AUTH_CODE` on the `-` character, allowing you to traverse through the newly-created elements in a `foreach` loop.

Comment: If you haven't altered IFS from its default, you can ignore the saving the value of IFS into OIFS parts and just `unset IFS` when you're done.

Comment: Could you explain the syntax `${AUTH_CODE[@]}`?  Is the `[@]` what causes bash to split the string?

Comment: I tested this on Linux, it seems like was only required to set the IFS, and after that, the string is already split.  ie: ` OIFS=$IFS;IFS='-';for s in $AUTH;do echo $s;done;IFS=$OIFS`  The `[@]` did not seem to be needed at all?

Answer (score 5):

You can use IFS but this is simpler:

```
echo "82a8-bd7d-986d-9dc9-41f5-fc02-2c20-3175-097a-c1eb"- \
  | while read -d - i; do echo "$i"; done
```

Please take notice of added `-` after string to split — read will ignore the last token otherwise.

Comment: this doesn't add the readability I want though, considering the operations on each element is rather intensive

Comment: I don't understand. What's not readable? You don't need to do this in one line — you can have as many lines as you want between `do` and `done`.

Answer (score 4):

Another way with pattern matching and array:

```
AUTH_CODE='82a8-bd7d-986d-9dc9-41f5-fc02-2c20-3175-097a-c1eb'
array=( ${AUTH_CODE//-/ } )
for j in ${array[@]} ; do echo $j ; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use parameters expansion:

```
AUTH_CODE='82a8-bd7d-986d-9dc9-41f5-fc02-2c20-3175-097a-c1eb'
echo "${AUTH_CODE//-/$'\n'}"
```

Output:

```
82a8
bd7d
986d
9dc9
41f5
fc02
2c20
3175
097a
c1eb
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {1..10}; do echo '82a8-bd7d-986d-9dc9-41f5-fc02-2c20-3175-097a-c1eb'|cut -d"-" -f$i;done
```

Comment: You might have missed the part about "no external binaries".